# すでに作成済みの"User"を安全に削除するためには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## 前提・やりたいこと

Rubu on railsにてtwitterログインを実装中です。
そのためにログイン用のユーザーモデルを作成したいです。

## うまくいかないこと

ユーザーモデル作成のためにターミナルに下記のコマンドを打ちました。

./bin/rails g model user provider:string uid:string nickname:string image_url:string

すると下記のエラーメッセージが表示されました。

## エラーメッセージ

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 66801
      invoke  active_record
The name 'User' is either already used in your application or reserved by
Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

## お伺いしたいこと

エラーメッセージを見る限りすでに「User」が使われてしまっているとのことですが、このモデルを新たに作りたいため、すでにある「User」を削除して、新しくこのユーザーモデルを作成するためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

以上

Answer (score 2):

やりたいことは、`User` に必要な項目を追加するという作業だと思います。Railsにはマイグレーションという仕組みがあり、データベースのテーブルにカラムを追加したり、削除したりすることができます。

```
rails g migration AddDeviseColumnsToUsers provider:string uid:string nickname:string image_url:string
```

とすると、`db/migrate` 以下にマイグレーションファイルが作成されるので、

```
rake db:migrate
```

してください。

マイグレーションについて詳しくは、[Rails Guides: Active Record マイグレーション](http://railsguides.jp/active_record_migrations.html) を参照してください。